# HTML and Text email with not clickable links

Tags: email, html-email, multipart

I am creating an Multipart HTML/TEXT email and came across a statement I often get myself after receiving registration and confirmation emails:

> If you are not redirected by clicking on the link, you can copy and
>   paste the link into the address window of your browser or enter
>   yourself there.

I personally never had issues with clicking on links in email, so I a would like to know under what circumstances or with wich email client a user might not be able to click on a link.

Answer (score 2):

Some email providers disable suspicious(or not) links for security reasons.

It does happen very often. So keep the sentence and the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

From time to time I receive e-mails where the link doesn't show as a hyperlink. I think the program which created the mail (which could be anything, doesn't need to be a regular mail program) didn't recognize/auto change it as / to a hyperlink and the writer of the mail didn't do that either. Sometimes this happens because the hyperlink doesn't start  with http or www, e.g. something like mydomain.com/somepage.htm. If you are sure you always format it correctly then there is less chance that it won't be clickable, but it still possible to fail in specific e-mail clients, on mails which have been altered by your anti-virus program or provider, etc.

So yes, add the message to be sure@

Answer (score 1):

Not all email clients can handle HTML emails, but it's less of a problem nowadays. But with so many different email clients out there, some may have to disabled HTML emails. In that case, your HTML won't be active in their email, so a plain text link is a solution.

You'll still reach most of your recipients without a hitch, though.

Comment: sorry I did not clarify enough that I have a multipart email

Comment: That doesn't really change the situation. If the recipient's preference is for text/plain and they have a renderer which doesn't make links clickable in plain text, they *will* need to copy/paste the URL to their browser, or something.